# PWM phase shift controller IC confusion

Tags: current, power-electronics, pwm, duty-cycle

I was reading one of the datasheets regarding the control of an H-bridge i.e. [UCC3895](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc3895.pdf?ts=1692293833189&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). As far as I understand, this is a PWM controller to drive a full bridge inverter. I have a few confusions regarding the IC:

1. What is the meaning of the current-mode operation, voltage mode-operation, etc. of the IC as shown below:

   [image]
2. How is the duty cycle of the output waves A, B, C, and D changed?
3. They have taken an example of designing a circuit for wave generation for the transformer. Why are they finding out the currents, etc. in this case? I have confusion understanding these calculations, any simple explanation of what they are basically doing in this will help. A sample screenshot from a part of the calculation is shown below:

[image]